# What does dsget use to query the directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, adldap

I am in an organization with an Active Directory with a very deep nested group structure.  I would like to query the directory to recursively find user members of a group from a Linux machine.  On a Windows machine,

```
dsget group "dn_of_group" -members -expand
```

does exactly what I want and does it very quickly.  When I tried to get the same results via LDAP with

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=dn_of_group)
```

the query takes almost a minute to run.  Does `dsget` use LDAP under the hood or does it use some other means to query the directory?  And if so, is there any way for me to also use that?

Edit:
Clarified that I need the members which are users.

Answer (score 0):

The framework 3.5 with [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299745.aspx) Namespace provides a method that searches all groups recursively and returns the groups in which the user is a member. The returned set may also include additional groups that system would consider the user a member of for authorization purposes.

```
UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups()
```

The groups that are returned by this method may include groups from a different scope and store than the principal. For example, if the principal is an AD DS object that has a DN of "CN=SpecialGroups,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com, the returned set can contain groups that belong to the "CN=NormalGroups,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com

---

In the other direction you've got :

```
GroupPrincipal.GetMembers(bool recursive)
```

See [Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339975)

Comment: I need to go the other direction.  I.e. find all the user members of a specified group, not find all the groups a specified user is a member of.